# how to use jquery isotope and mansory with angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, directive, jquery-isotope

jquery with angular directive

```
 var $document_body = $(document.body);
 var $portfolio_gallery = $(".gallery-isotope");
 var portfolio_filter = ".portfolio-filter a";
 var $portfolio_filter_first_child = $(".portfolio-filter a:eq(0)");
 var $portfolio_flex_slider = $(".portfolio-slider");
 var isotope_mode;
        if ($portfolio_gallery.hasClass("masonry")){
            isotope_mode = "masonry";
        } else{
            isotope_mode = "fitRows";
        }

        //isotope firsttime loading
        $portfolio_gallery.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $portfolio_gallery.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
                layoutMode: isotope_mode,
                filter: "*"
            });
        });

        //isotope filter
        $document_body.on('click', portfolio_filter, function(e) {
            $(portfolio_filter).removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            var fselector = $(this).data('filter');

            $portfolio_gallery.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
                layoutMode: isotope_mode,
                filter: fselector
            });
            return false;
        });
```

how to make angular directive with this jquery
and to use jqlite

### when running this jquery code in my controller the functions are not working properly

##